# Where are the "Unified Brush" Settings?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I'm watching a Blender 2.8 [sculpting tutorial](https://youtu.be/A-Wq8K8icpQ?t=232) and don't have the unified brush settings.

Where can I find them in Blender 2.82+ ?

Comment: I've never heard of a unified brush. All I could find is [Use Unified Radius](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tool_settings/brush_settings.html). Where did you hear about it and what is its purpose? Care to elaborate? If so, please use the edit link below your question to add additional info.

Comment: That might be it thanks you, do you know where it is in blender? "Unified size" was actually what I was looking for sorry, 3:56 on this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-Wq8K8icpQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unified Brush settings have been moved from the menu to "Properties - Tool Settings".

You find them on the right side of the Radius and Strength settings, represented by a globe icon.

To access them more quickly, you can always add them to your Quick Favorites Menu (RMB - "Add to Quick Favorites Menu").

[image: unified brush settings]

Comment: I never would have figured that out, thanks a million!!

Comment: @moddaflodda - Please don't post "Thank you" comments. If answers on StackExchange solved your problem, [vote on them and mark them as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)